# How to License Visual Studio 2013 with another Microsoft or organization account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have tried a large number of VS2013 re-installations (using ISO image download link from "MSDN Subscriptions" website), registry tweaks and manual file repairs/changes.

Finally I got to the problem resolving point where I got this dialog:

[Link to VS2013 License Dialog](http://www.mediafire.com/view/6w42wam6yf4a2qu/mic_lic.png)

And that was the first time ever I saw the link "License with another Microsoft or organization account" on that dialog. Last thing I did before I got that link was:

- deleted regkey HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\E79B3F9C-6543-4897-BBA5-5BFB0A02BB5C
- ran VS2013 uninstall from Control Panel and repaired the installation

Problem is I have no clue whether it really helped since I cannot reproduce the success on the computers of my co-workers in that way.

We have MSDN Subcription that contains 5 licenses for VS2013 Pro and we have only used 2 so far (head developer (zd**** on the pic right side) and me (dm**** on the pic left side)).

Is there maybe any downloadable ISO image of VS2013 Pro with that link embedded and enabled by default, or any reg tweak to enable it?

Incidentally, I have also tried almost every link and option on "MSDN Subscriptions", "Microsoft VLSC" and "Microsoft Partner" sites and tried filling a number of contact forms from those websites and even sent a few e-mails. However I did not get any replies - not a single information from Microsoft.

Only contact with them I had was talking to a Live chat guy and to my great surprise, my problem was not in his jurisdiction so he gave me a link to a contact form.

Comment: `We have MSDN Subcription that contains 5 licenses for VS2013 Pro` -- Are you sure about that? MSDN subscriptions are **per individual**. You may be able to install it five times, but that **does not mean** five people can use it.

Comment: just uninstall Visual Studios , then re-install with the ISO from your subscription page, you don't need any keys - if you really have an MSDN account with 5 subscriptions in it then the key comes in the ISO file , it will register itself

Comment: I have a feeling you guys haven't read my entire thing. 
- to TZHX Yes we have more than one license or I would'nt be able to unlock it on my computer
- to Scott Shelby Yes I tried that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a third-party support issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some juggling with several different computer I finally realised what was the difference between theirs and mine. I was the only who had VS2013 Pro with Update 4.
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4 to be exact.
So after applying that update to other computers I was able to get the mentioned link and came to a long lasting peace of mind :)

Answer (score 0):

In the top right hand corner of a running Visual Studio 2013, just below the quick find box and the minimise, expand and close buttons, there is an area that shows who is signed in. Clicking the name there brings up an account settings option that is very similar to the page in your link.

Perhaps if you sign in as a user who has links to multiple Microsoft accounts then the text "*License with another Microsoft or organization account*" will be shown. Perhaps you need to visit the administration pages of the Microsoft account you want to use and add the appropriate users (ie email addresses) to that account.

Comment: Microsoft really need to test this garbage. My alt account is valid. The old account is not. Their options don't let me switch and just throw errors and leave me with an infinite loop of frustration.